# Estimating the duration of a computationally-intensive process

Tags: soft-question, exponential-function, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics, estimation

I'm not sure if it's even possible to create a mathematical model given the data I have, but I'll post this question with optimistic hope.

I'm running a computational process for which I do not have access to the source code (it uses Microsoft's closed source code).

The process finds duplicate lines (rows) in a text file and reports the duplicates along with the count of the number of occurrences for each duplicate.

Specifically, the command to do this, in Windows PowerShell, is:

```
 Get-Content .\input.txt | Group-Object | Select Name, Count > output.txt
```

I performed a test with a small sample, and I found that 5,000 lines (with the median length of each line being 50 characters) takes approximately 1 second to complete.

I then performed a test with a larger sample, and I found that 50,000 lines (with the same median line length) takes approximately 2 minutes to complete.

I then performed a test with a larger sample, and I found that 75,000 lines (with the same median line length) takes approximately 3.5 minutes to complete.

I then performed another test with an even larger sample, and I found that 100,000 lines (with the same median line length) takes approximately 8 minutes to complete.

I'm now running the same process on a file with 2,000,000 lines (with the same median line length).

It appears that PowerShell is limited to 4GB RAM, so the threads performing this task are using the maximum memory possible for PowerShell.

This process has been running for over 19 hours.  There is no progress indicator.

I'm trying to estimate the time it will take for this process to complete.

The challenge is the duration of such a process is not linearly dependent on the size of the input.

I'm trying to make a reasonable guesstimate, and I'm struggling to settle on an appropriate mathematical expression to use to provide such an estimate.

I'm hoping someone here will be able to recommend their suggested expression, and perhaps explain their reason why they think their recommendation is a good choice.

Comment: With one data point it is impossible to determine. You'd need to determine the run length for several sized inputs to make an estimate

Comment: @Aphyd Thanks. I agree, but I am/was hoping someone would be able to provide a useful expression based on the likely computational complexity of the process.  BTW, how many data points do you think will be sufficient, especially given the 4GB of usable RAM becomes a factor at some point?

Comment: There's a world of difference (like factors of 1,000) once all your data no longer fits in memory, and starts using disk to back your virtual memory. It might not be quite so bad if you've got SSD instead of magnetic disk storage, but it's still going to make prediction impossible.

Comment: That said, this smells roughly like sorting, where lots of good algorithms hit a best case complexity of $n \log(n)$. Don't know how you can make sure, or check, that PowerShell will do so.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thanks for your feedback.  Regarding using disk as virtual memory, I might be mistaken, but I think the process has a maximum addressable memory space of 4GB, and since there is more than 4GB of available RAM on that box, that issue is not present in this specific case.  In other cases, yes, definitely, I agree with you 100%.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Regarding your second comment (very helpful BTW... thanks!), I was thinking along the lines of *n* log(*n*) as well.  I think estimating the case complexity is key, and that's where I could really use some help right now.

Comment: Okay. And I'll guess this is out of scope, but I'd switch to something like Linux+Perl for this task. It doesn't seem like something PowerShell is optimized for. It might be that your anti-virus is adding a bunch of time on Windows.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Very long story short, I agree.  After 48 hours, I had to repurpose that CPU core, and thus stop PowerShell.  I then wrote my own optimized code, and it was able to get the job done in under an hour.  Still, I welcome additional answers, because I find this topic intriguing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have many sample points, but I'll still share some speculations, just know that they're credibility may be jeopardized by lack of data.

I plotted your data on a log-log time (sec) vs. size plot, and noticed that the first point is abnormally large, but the other three form a nice line. I suspect that there's a large amount of overhead (pre-sorting?) being done, that dominates the running time until the input grows large enough. Ignoring this data point, I can draw a linear regression line through the remaining three points, which fits extremely nicely, with a $R^2$ value of $0.99$ The equation of the line is

$$
Y = 1.98 X - 7.24
$$

However, remember that this is a log-log plot, so $Y = \log(y)$ and $X = \log(x)$. Substituting that in, we get:

$$
\begin{align}
\log(y) &= 1.98 \log(x) - 7.24 \\
\log(y) &= \log(x^{1.98}) - 7.24 \\
y &= 10^{\log(x^{1.98}) - 7.24} \\
y &= 10^{\log(x^{1.98})}10^{-7.24} \\
y &= 10^{-7.24}x^{1.98}
\end{align}
$$

That means our running time is dominated by a term of order $1.98$. Likely, this means the algorithm dominating the running time is quadratic.

Plugging into this (very rough) estimate, I get that for $x = 2,000,000$, the runtime is estimated around $2$ days ($47.8$ hours). Bear in mind that that's estimated from three data points.

Comment: Thank you Dillon. Upvoted! I played around with things too, and the median of my estimates were similar to your estimate (median was 58 hours).  I have a question regarding your post.  The equation you presented is linear, but you mentioned that "likely... the algorithm dominating the running time is quadratic".  Can you add to your answer why this makes sense?  BTW, I actually used quadratic equations for most of my estimates, so your conclusion correlates with my primary hypothesis.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket updated - let me know if anything else needs cleared up